# How to load vue components from imported gem to the lib directory in rails?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, ruby-on-rails-5, vue-component, webpacker

We are using Ruby [Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) for loading JavaScripts in to webpage. 
currently we have set paths as below in webpacker.yml

```
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
```

This works fine and loads all assets from the given path.

**Question:**
In my application, we are trying to load assets from third party library **lib/** directory which contains javascript files as shown below folder structure.

How to load asset **(file1.vue) from lib directory into packs**.

**For reference**

> This is the folder structure currently we have:

```
-root
 |
 |-app
   |-javascript
     |-packs
       |-[pack files]
 |-lib
   |- app1
      |-app
        |-javascript
          |- shared
            |- components
              |- fields
                |- file1.vue
```

file1.vue, this file doesn't get load while inspecting assets in the chrome browser under the source tab.

I can not see file content under the fields folder

Webpack folder structure

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

After installing bundle of imported gem and starting webpack into it then it's worked.

```
gem update --system

bundle install

run webpack-dev-server
```